# Where is the favourites folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, favorites

I wanted to copy my favourites links from another machine onto a newly installed Windows 7 machine, but the system won't let me paste them into the Favourites folder showing at the top of Windows Explorer.

I can't see the old \Documents and Settings\User\Favourites on the C:\ drive any more, so where are they stored now?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The **Documents and Settings** folder simply changed name to **Users** in Vista and Windows 7.

> %USERPROFILE%\Favorites

will work on all versions.

Answer (score 50):

The favourites folder for **IE** in windows7 is located in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Favorites
```

The favourites folder for **windows explorer sidebar** in windows7 is located in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Links
```

Comment: yeah, this is what i was looking for (links)

Answer (score 16):

As well as the %USERPROFILE% trick, this also works from the Start Menu or Run dialog:

```
shell:favorites
```

Comment: In addition to this, you can also use `shell:links` to point to your favourites folder for windows explorer sidebar. This format is needed for registry keys. This was my case and wasn't explained anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
%systemdrive%\Users\%username%\Favorites\
```

If you copy and paste that line in to run, you should be able to get to your IE favourites.

Comment: Correct, but there are better, Windows version independent answers here.

Comment: The question stated Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, they're stored in: C:\Users\username\Favorites (or simply `%userprofile%\Favorites`).

From there, you can right-click on the file, copy it and save it to a flash drive in case your computer crashes, you will have all of your favorites.

If you have to buy a new computer or have to do a clean install of the operating system, you can go to your new computer's favorites and transfer your old favorites to it.

Answer (score 0):

Look under \Users\username, the Favorites folder is there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:/Users`.

You should see a list `AppData, Public, <your user name>`. Click on the user name – in my case "Ric".

`Favorites` is in here along with `Contacts, My Music, My Pictures, Downloads, My Documents, Desktop` etc, unlike in Windows XP where you had to hunt in different places for these files, Windows 7 has them all in the one folder.

Comment: That doesn't really add any useful information (the other answers all basically said the same). Also note that the folder is **not** called like your computer, but rather like your user profile name.

Answer (score -3):

Remember for you to view th favourites folder under  C:\Users\Steve\Favorites   you must first enable the view hidden files and system files

Comment: Not true, the Favorites folder is not hidden by default.