# Is there a way to open explorer in virtual favorites?

Tags: windows-explorer

The topmost item in my explorer is "Favorites"
This is my jump list to my most frequently used folders and I would like to open explorer with this folder expanded.
I found that I can open explorer in myComputer view with %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe ,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} but I could not find a way to open the virtual "Favorites" folder.
I am not talking about my internet favorites at %USERPROFILE%\Favorites.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/37671/where-is-the-favourites-folder-in-windows-7 (see answer about %USERPROFILE%\Links)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the folder named "Favorites" is in fact %USERPROFILE%\Links.
Thus creating a link as:  explorer.exe /root=%USERPROFILE%\Links opens the favorites folder in the right pane.
Alas, the left pane does not have the topmost item "Favorites" selected.
Instead I find myself deep in my %USERPROFILE% folder.
There seems to be no way to get the windows explorer start with showing the topmost item on the left pane.